# Getting the "value" out of a dynamically generated drop down list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I can get value when I am using a static dropdown list, but as soon as I change to a dynamically generated list value is always blank.

Anyone have any ideas?  Is it even possible to get the value out of a dynamic element?

**JS :**

```
$('#input_baseUrl').ready(function(){
    var newSelect=document.createElement('select');
    var selectHTML="";

    for(var count=0; count<services.length; count=count+1){
        var tempString = services[count].split("/");
        var serviceName = tempString[3];
        selectHTML+= "<option value='"+services[count]+"'>"+serviceName+"</option>";
    }

    //iniatilize a new select with the data we provided
    newSelect.innerHTML= selectHTML;
    //find the DOM element that is called input_baseURL
    document.getElementById("input_baseUrl").appendChild(newSelect);

});

function setURL() {
    var url = document.getElementById("input_baseUrl").value;
    alert($('#input_baseUrl').val());  // not sure if jQuery will work here but I have to try
    window.alert("THE URL is: " + url);
    var element = document.getElementById("input_baseUrl");
    var strUser = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    window.alert("Third option is: " +strUser);
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<form id='api_selector'>
     <div class='input' id="input_baseUrl" onchange="setURL()" name="baseUrl" type="text"></div>
     <div class='input'><input placeholder="api_key" id="input_apiKey" name="apiKey" type="text"/></div>
     <div class='input'><a id="explore" href="#">Explore</a></div>
</form>
```

Comment: The "input_baseUrl" element you're fetching is a `div`. You need to fetch the `select`.  `var element = document.getElementById("input_baseUrl");` <- a div.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. But you'll have to use a more elaborated selector:

```js
$('#input_baseUrl select option:selected').val();
```

But I think your HTML has a problem on the following line, did you mean this to be two tags, an `input` inside a `div`?

```
<div class='input' id="input_baseUrl" onchange="setURL()" name="baseUrl" type="text"></div>
```

To fix it, separate it in two tags, and give your `div` an `id`:

```
<form id='api_selector'>
     <div class='input' id="div_baseUrl">
         <input id="input_baseUrl" onchange="setURL()" name="baseUrl" type="text"/>
     </div>
     ...
</form>
```

You can then add the `newSelect` to your `div` from your `ready()` function:

```js
document.getElementById("div_baseUrl").appendChild(newSelect);
```

After this, your `setUrl()` function can be:

```js
function setURL() {
    var url = $('#input_baseUrl').val();
    var strUser = $('#div_baseUrl select option:selected').val();
}
```

Comment: Yes the input goes inside the DIV, the HTML comes from the Swagger UI which I am modifying.  Thank you for the assistance.  I will try your suggestions.